# Remove column in awk command

Tags: unix, awk, split

I want to remove column as for now i have command that include splitting, header and trailer in one command. I wanted to do splitting, header, trailer and *remove first 3 columns* in one command.

My original output is

```
  Country   Gender    Plate       Name        Account Number        Car Name
    X        F          A          Fara        XXXXXXXXXX            Ixora
    X        F          b          Jiha        XXXXXXXXXX            Saga
    X        M          c          Jiji        XXXXXXXXXX            Proton
```

My splited files:

*first file*

06032017

```
  Country   Gender    Plate       Name    Account Number     Car Name        
    X        F          A     Fara        XXXXXXXXXX         Ixora
```

EOF 1

*second file*
06032017

```
  Country   Gender    Plate       Name        Account Number        Car Name
    X        F          b          Jiha        XXXXXXXXXX            Saga
```

EOF1

My desitre output:

06032017

```
    Name    Account Number     Car Name        
    Fara        XXXXXXXXXX         Ixora
```

EOF 1

06032017

```
  Name        Account Number        Car Name
  Jiha        XXXXXXXXXX            Saga
```

EOF1

This is my splitted command:

```
awk -v date="$(date +"%d%m%Y")" -F\| 'NR==1 {h=$0; next} 
{file="CAR_V1_"$1"_"$2"_"date".csv"; print (a[file]++?"": "DETAIL "date"" ORS h ORS) $0 > file}
END{for(file in a) print "EOF " a[file] > file}' HIRE_PURCHASE_testing.csv
```

Comment: Obviously, your code does nothing to remove the third column. What have you tried so far? If you want to remove the first three columns, first of all you must not print the whole line (`$0`). In other words, you should **remove the first three words in every line**

Comment: What does question have to do with bash?

Comment: `cut -f4- $yourFile`?

Comment: @Jiji - Please confirm your input and output file/s and what is the use of my original output file here.

Answer (score 1):

To get an idea how to skip some fields:

```
$ echo "Field1 Field2 Field3 Field4 Field5 Field6"  |awk '{print $0}'
Field1 Field2 Field3 Field4 Field5 Field6  #No skipping here. Printed just for comparison

$ echo "Field1 Field2 Field3 Field4 Field5 Field6"  |awk '{print substr($0, index($0,$4))}'
Field4 Field5 Field6

$ echo "Field1 Field2 Field3 Field4 Field5 Field6"  |awk '{$1=$2=$3="";print}'
   Field4 Field5 Field6
#Mind the gaps in the beginning. You can use this if you need to "delete" particular columns.
#Actually you are not really delete columns but replace their contents with a blank value.

$ echo "Field1 Field2 Field3 Field4 Field5 Field6"  |awk '{gsub($1FS$2FS$3FS$4,$4);print}'
Field4 Field5 Field6   #Columns 1-2-3-4 have been replaced by column4. No gaps here.

$ echo "Field1 Field2 Field3 Field4 Field5 Field6"  |awk '{print $4,$5,$6}' 
Field4 Field5 Field6
# If you have a fixed number of fields (i.e 6 fields) you can just do not print the first three fields and print the last three fields
```

Adapted to your existed code, the line

```
print (a[file]++?"": "DETAIL "date"" ORS h ORS) $0 > file
```

If changed to

```
print (a[file]++?"": "DETAIL "date"" ORS h ORS) substr($0, index($0,$4)) > file
```

Or to

```
print (a[file]++?"": "DETAIL "date"" ORS h ORS) $4,$5,$6 > file #if you have a fixed number of columns in the file)
```

should be enough.

I would sugggest next time you need help, simplify the problem to get help more easily. For the rest users is kind of hard to fully follow you.

Also have a look here to see how all those functions work in details: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html

Comment: @Jiji Updated . Is it ok?

Comment: I understand u teach how. but the first 3 columns still stay...not dropped..how? @GeorgeVasiliou

Comment: @Jiji Did you try the substr method as advised in my answer?

Comment: I think the command u show is for row..i try change $0 to $4 still the same and I remove the $0..the row dissapear.. @GeorgeVasiliou Ya I did substr...but it effect the row not column..

Comment: If the files has fixed number of columns you can try my second advise (`print $4,$5,$6`). You could also try the `gsub` method, but this method should work: `print (a[file]++?"": "DETAIL "date"" ORS h ORS) substr($0, index($0,$4)) > file`

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou..I tried both :'( but still the result is the same :'(

Comment: I have a lot of column..cannot fix it..i hve around 15++ columns @GeorgeVasiliou

Comment: What is the exact command you are using? It is strange the first three columns remain. Works fine in my tests.

Comment: awk -v date="$(date +"%d%m%Y")" -F\| 'NR==1 {h=$0; next} 
{file="INITIATION_V1_"$1"_"$2"_"date".csv";  
print (a[file]++?"": "DETAIL "date"" ORS h ORS) **substr($0, index($0,$4))** > file} END{for(file in a) print "EOF " a[file] > file}'HIRE_PURCHASE_testing.csv  this my command..I just add up the **substr($0, index($0,$4))** @GeorgeVasiliou

Comment: or i need to drop the header and trailer first? But it doesnot work at all